# OOP: How to write pythonic interaction between classes?

Tags: python, oop

I would like to model the interaction between two classes where one of the classes takes the other one as an argument in one of its methods. Which class should be in the argument of the method of the other class?

I have written two alternative solutions to the problem but I am not sure which one of them is considered to be the correct way of handling this issue. Maybe there is even a better way but here are my two alternatives:

```
class BankAccount:

    def __init__(self, balance):
        self._balance = balance

    def transaction(self, cash):
        self._balance += cash._value
        cash._value = 0


class Cash:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def transfer(self, bank_account):
        bank_account._balance += self._value
        self._value = 0


if __name__ == "__main__":

# First alternative
    acc = BankAccount(balance=100)
    cash = Cash(value=10)

    print('-' * 30)
    print('First alternative')
    print(f'Account balance before: {acc._balance}')
    print(f'Cash value before: {cash._value}')
    acc.transaction(cash=cash)
    print(f'Account balance after: {acc._balance}')
    print(f'Cash value after: {cash._value}')

# Second alternative
    acc = BankAccount(balance=100)
    cash = Cash(value=10)

    print('-' * 30)
    print('Second alternative')
    print(f'Account balance before: {acc._balance}')
    print(f'Cash value before: {cash._value}')
    cash.transfer(bank_account=acc)
    print(f'Account balance after: {acc._balance}')
    print(f'Cash value after: {cash._value}')
```

As you can see, both alternatives show the same results but I'd be happy to get a recommendation for the pythonic way of modelling this kind of class interaction. Thanks.

Comment: Why would a paycheck value go to 0 when paid out? Processing a paycheck is not something a bank account does, nor would a paycheck do this. It's something the *bank* does, which then interacts with the bankaccount balance, and marking the paycheck as processed. That's what you are modelling here, *business processes*, code should usually reflect such processes directly unless there is a clearly better process to model instead.

Comment: Put diffently: **neither** class should do this, nor should you alter the paycheck value. You wiped the historical record of the paycheck, which should be considered *immutable* instead.

Comment: I feel like this should be more a financial question than a programming one

Comment: More generally it is a bad idea for one class to modify another class' member data.  The point of classes is to abstract the data and leave an interface that the programmer controls.  Instead provide a way to get the `paycheck._value` value and provide that value to `acc`.  It is bad practice in all programming languages to access member data outside of the class which owns that data.  In this case, if you want to reset the `_value` to 0, provide a function `reset` or something that `acc` can call after getting the value from a getter function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I changed it from a paycheck class to a cash class if that works better for you.

Comment: That Python does not prohibit access to local instance variables of an unrelated class does not mean it is a good idea. All of these access should be channelled via methods.

Answer (score 0):

The example is ill-formed which prevents us from concentrating on actual OOP. It does not make sense for some *cash* to lose its value because it is tranfered. Does a $20 bill lose its value because you deposit it at the bank?

### A new example

Instead let's consider the problem of representing money transfer between two bank accounts.

A key concept of OOP is that attributes of an instance should not be directly updated. Instead, the instance should provide an API via methods which provide some control over its state.

We can accomplish that by defining the methods `deposit` and `withdraw` for a `BankAccount`. This way, we can then define the method `transfer_to` which only makes use of this API.

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance = 0

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if amount >= self.balance:
            self.balance -= amount
        else:
            raise ValueError('Insufficient funds')

    def transfer_to(self, target, amount):
        if isinstance(target, BankAccount):
            self.withdraw(amount)
            target.deposit(amount)
        else:
            raise ValueError("'target' must be another BankAccount")
```

### Advantage

By encapsulating the logic of `withdraw`, `deposit` and `tranfer_to`, we allow for simple implementation of more complex types of accounts through inheritance.

Here let's give the example of a new type of `BankAccount` which allows for negative balance.

```
class CreditAccount(BankAccount):
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self._balance -= amount
```

By fully delegating the responsability of withdrawing to instances of `BankAccount`, we allow external agents to manipulate an account without having to be aware of the inner logic of withdrawing and depositing.